# Fuction can not interpret nan value

Tags: python, pandas, function, nan, fillna

I am trying to get rid of NaN values in a dataframe.
Instead of filling NaN with averages or doing ffill I wanted to fill missing values according to the destribution of values inside a column.
In other words, if a column has 120 rows, 20 are NaN, 80 contain 1.0 and 20 contain 0,0, I want to fill 80% of NaN values with 1. Note that the column contains floats.

I made a function to do so:

```
def fill_cr_hist(x):
    if x is pd.np.nan:
        r = random.random()
        if r > 0.80:
            return 0.0
        else:
            return 1.0
    else:
        return x
```

However when I call the function it does not change NaN values.

```
df['Credit_History'] = df['Credit_History'].apply(fill_cr_hist)
```

I thied filling NaN values with pd.np.nan, but it didn't change anything.

```
df['Credit_History'].fillna(value=pd.np.nan, inplace=True)
df['Credit_History'] = df['Credit_History'].apply(fill_cr_hist)
```

The other function I wrote that is almost identical and works fine. In that case the column contains strings.

```
def fill_self_emp(x):
    if x is pd.np.nan:
        r = random.random()
        if r > 0.892442:
            return 'Yes'
        else:
            return 'No'
    else:
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ser = pd.Series([
    1, 1, np.nan, 0, 0, 1, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, 0, 0, np.nan])
```

Use `value_counts` with `normalize=True` to get a list of probabilities corresponding to your values. Then generate values randomly according to the given probability distribution and use `fillna` to fill NaNs.

```
p = ser.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index().tolist()   
u = np.sort(ser.dropna().unique())
ser = ser.fillna(pd.Series(np.random.choice(u, len(ser), p=p)))
```

This solution should work for *any* number of numeric/categorical values, not just 0s and 1s. If data is a string type, use `pd.factorize` and convert to numeric.

---

**Details**

First, compute the probability distribution:

```
ser.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()

0.0    0.444444
1.0    0.555556
dtype: float64
```

Get a list of unique values, sorted in the same way:

```
np.sort(ser.dropna().unique())
array([0., 1.])
```

Finally, generate random values with specified probability distribution.

```
pd.Series(np.random.choice(u, len(ser), p=p))

0     0.0
1     0.0
2     1.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     1.0
7     1.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    1.0
11    0.0
12    1.0
dtype: float64
```